# What does the verb "umsetzen" mean in a business writing context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this sentence in a business news journal published in Germany, and written by an author with a German surname, so I assume he is a native speaker:

> Das war in den 90er Jahren, als der Konzern noch 500 Millionen Euro **umsetzte**.

What does *umsetzte* mean there?  Had sales of?  Was valued at? Something else?

Comment: It refers to _business volume_.

Comment: So "had sales of" would be an idiomatic way to render it in English?

Comment: Check what _Umsatz_ means in German (business related) language: https://dict.leo.org/german-english/umsatz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to the noun "Umsatz", but the author wants to use a verb. Some alternatives are

> Der Umsatz des Konzerns betrug 500 Millionen Euro.
>
> Der Konzern hatte/machte einen Umsatz von 500 Millionen Euro.

Umsatz means revenue, usually without value added tax (Umsatzsteuer).

Answer (score 0):

Ask uncle Duden who as a bonus gives also insight into the genesis of the word:

[image]

(Screenshot from Duden Bibliothek Express Version 6.1.0.0., issued in 2015, lemma *umsetzen*. Would be similarly explained in the printed book Duden Universalwörterbuch, 8th edition.)